# Retorno de dados com Angular

Tags: angular, ionic, typescript, ionic3

Possuo um service com a seguinte estrutura:

```js
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import 'rxjs-compat/add/operator/map';
import {map} from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class BlockchainService {
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
    url = 'https://blockchain.info/q/getdifficulty';

    getDifficulty() {
        return this.http.get(this.url)
            .pipe(map(res => res)) // pega os dados sempre q estiver disponível e remapeia
            .subscribe(data  => data, error => console.log('erro')); // subscribe ouve um observable
    }
}
```

E estou chamando dessa forma

```js
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {BlockchainService} from '../blockchain.service';
import {Subscriber, Subscription} from 'rxjs';
import * as util from 'util';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tab1',
  templateUrl: 'tab1.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['tab1.page.scss']
})
export class Tab1Page {
  dificuldade: Subscription;
  constructor(blockchainService: BlockchainService) {
   this.dificuldade = blockchainService.getDifficulty();
  }


}
```

O problema é que no front, ao chamar com interpolação `{{dificuldade}}`, só retorna `[object Object]` e, ao inspecionar, ele tem a estrutura a seguir, que não contempla os dados que deveria receber

```js
{ closed: false, _parentOrParents: null, _subscriptions: [ { closed: false, _parentOrParents: [Circular], _subscriptions: [Object], syncErrorValue: null, syncErrorThrown: false, syncErrorThrowable: true, isStopped: false, destination: [Circular], project: [Function], count: 0, thisArg: [Circular] } ], syncErrorValue: null, syncErrorThrown: false, syncErrorThrowable: true, isStopped: false, destination: { closed: false, _parentOrParents: null, _subscriptions: null, syncErrorValue: null, syncErrorThrown: false, syncErrorThrowable: false, isStopped: false, destination: { closed: true, next: [Function: next], error: [Function: error], complete: [Function: complete] }, _parentSubscriber: [Circular], _context: [Circular], _next: [Function], _error: [Function], _complete: undefined } }
```

Como devo obter esses dados corretamente? Caso eu passe um `console.log` no primeiro parâmetro do subscribe, consigo imprimir da forma desejada no console

Comment: Oque esta esperando como retorno da url ? Que tipo de dado ? Um json ?

Comment: Uma string.

A api é aberta, pode ver: https://blockchain.info/q/getdifficulty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenta assim:

```
{{dificuldade|async}}
```

isso se da pq dificuldade é um observable e não seus dados em si.

Comment: É, não funcionou

Comment: Tira o subscribe do seu serviço

Comment: Já tirei e passei para o component, mas ainda não consigo acessar o valor diretamente pra setar na variável "dificuldade"

Comment: Descobri qual era o problema, faltava o "this.init();" no construtor. Coisa boba, mas passou batido. 

Obrigado pela ajuda